# Randomly Populating Foreign Key In Sample Data Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, test-data, sample-data, data-generation

I'm generating test data for a new database, and I'm having trouble populating one of the foreign key fields. I need to create a relatively large number (1000) of entries in a table (`SurveyResponses`) that has a foreign key to a table with only 6 entries (`Surveys`)

The database already has a `Schools` table that has a few thousand records. For arguments sake lets say it looks like this

```
Schools
+----+-------------+
| Id | School Name |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | PS 1        |
|  2 | PS 2        |
|  3 | PS 3        |
|  4 | PS 4        |
|  5 | PS 5        |
+----+-------------+
```

I'm creating a new `Survey` table. It will only have about 3 rows.

```
Survey
+----+-------------+
| Id |    Col2     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 2014 Survey |
|  2 | 2015 Survey |
|  3 | 2016 Survey |
+----+-------------+
```

`SurveyResponses` simply ties a school to a survey.

```
Survey Responses
+----+----------+----------+
| Id | SchoolId | SurveyId |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 |
|  2 |        2 |        2 |
|  3 |        3 |        1 |
|  4 |        4 |        3 |
|  5 |        5 |        2 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Populating the `SurveyId` field is what's giving me the most trouble. I can randomly select 1000 Schools, but I haven't figured out a way to generate 1000 random SurveyIds. I've been trying to avoid a while loop, but maybe that's the only option?

I've been using Red Gate SQL Data Generator to generate some of my test data, but in this case I'd really like to understand how this can be done with raw SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, using a correlated subquery to get a random survey associated with each school:

```
select s.schoolid,
       (select top 1 surveyid
        from surveys
        order by newid()
       ) as surveyid
from schools s;
```

Note:  This doesn't seem to work.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/647) is a SQL Fiddle showing the non-workingness.  I am quite surprised it doesn't work, because `newid()` should be a

EDIT:

If you know the survey ids have no gaps and start with 1, you can do:

```
select 1 + abs(checksum(newid()) % 3) as surveyid
```

I did check that this does work.

EDIT II:

This appears to be overly aggressive optimization (in my opinion).  Correlating the query appears to fix the problem.  So, something like this should work:

```
select s.schoolid,
       (select top 1 surveyid
        from surveys s2
        where s2.surveyid = s.schoolid or s2.surveyid <> s.schoolid -- nonsensical condition to prevent over optimization
        order by newid()
       ) as surveyid
from schools s;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/664) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating this.

Comment: I tried that, but all the surveyid were the same in the result

Comment: @pnewhook . . . That is quite strange.  I offer another solution which I consider much less elegant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have a very similar question and don't want to post a new question. Q) From two tables with PK, FK relationship- **how can I very simply select the top 5 from `BedSizeTable` reference table, and populate king/Queen/Single Text into the secondary `HotelRoomsTable`?**    I would like to turn this into store proc if possible.

Comment: @aggie . . . The appropriate way to ask a question is as a question, not in a comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am afraid it will get shot down as redundant by the SO  poleecee  :) but if you will answer I will post it :D